# Casting an Int as a String from a Realm result Swift

Tags: swift, string, option-type

I am asking this hesitantly as I know this is probably a dumb question.

I am returning a Realm result and then have gone ahead and tried to cast it to a String as normal (to put in a text label).

However I'm getting an error `'init' has been renamed to 'init(describing:)'`.

When I try use the describing method instead, the label prints `"Optional"` inside it which obviously isn't what I want.

Is there a reason I can't use :

```
previousTimeLabel.text = String(lastRecord?.time)
```

I'm sure I've done this before and it's been fine, am I missing something?  (`lastRecord.time` is an Int).

I've checked the answer here about Interpolation [Swift String Interpolation displaying optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417853/swift-string-interpolation-displaying-optional) and tried changing to something like this :

```
    if let previousRounds = String(lastRecord?.rounds) {
        previousRoundsLabel.text = previousRounds
    }
```

but get the same error + `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift String Interpolation displaying optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417853/swift-string-interpolation-displaying-optional)

Comment: thanks will check it out - what I don't understand is that elsewhere in my code I have         cell.repsNumber.text = String(exerciseName.reps)
which works fine!

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with Realm or the variable being an `Int`. It's due to `lastRecord` being `Optional` and hence due to the optional chaining, `lastRecord?.time` is `Optional` as well.

Comment: okay thanks - but I don't understand why that means I can't cast as a String (sorry - I'm still pretty new, I might be missing something obvious here) - i've also tried force unwrapping with ! but that doesn't work

Comment: I've marked your question as a duplicate for a reason. The answers their show several ways for solving your issue. You have to unwrap the Optional using a default value, optional binding or force unwrapping, as explained in the answers for the linked question. You are not casting at all, casting is done using the `as` keyword. You're _converting_ the value to `String` by calling its designated initializer. The conversion succeeds without error.

Comment: The text property of a UITextField is an Optional String so you don’t have to unwrap the string when assigning it directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't `String(lastRecord?.time)` being `Optional`. The issue is `lastRecord` being `Optional`, so you have to unwrap `lastRecord`, not the return value of `String(lastRecord?.time)`.

```
if let lastRecord = lastRecord {
    previousRoundsLabel.text = "\(lastRecord.time)"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To summarize Dávid Pásztor's answer, here's *a* way you can fix it:

```
previousTimeLabel.text = String(lastRecord?.time ?? 0)
```

This may not be the best way for your application.  The point Dávid was making is that you need to deal with lastRecord possibly being nil before trying to pass its time Int into the String initializer.  So the above is one simple way to do that, if you're ok with having "0" string as your previousTimeLabel's text if there was no lastRecord.

Comment: this worked for me thank you but I ended up using David's example so I can mix in some interpolation too - thanks so much - this explanation really helped